# How to label "H₂O" in gwt label text

Tags: gwt

My problem is that I haven't any idea how to label "H₂O" in GWT label text.
I want to set "2" at the base of "H" within GWT label text. My code is

```
<g:Label text="H2O"></g:Label>
```

It shows "H2O".

Answer (score 2):

Try `&#x2082;` Instead of the 2. It should produce a subscript 2, which is what you want. It is a unicode XML entity. Not sure if gwt decodes them though.

Comment: Added the x, forgot that it is the hex version of the code.

Comment: GWT uses an XML parser (Xerces) so yes it'll work. Or you could just type in the character in the file, as it has to be in UTF-8 anyway.